# Email table data as attachment, get table name and emal id as parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql, smtp, plsqldeveloper

I'm tryng to code something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMAIL_TABLE (errbuf         OUT      VARCHAR2,
                       retcode        OUT      NUMBER
                      ) is
cursor head is
select column_name
from all_tab_columns a
where table_name= 'EMP'
order by column_id;         

cursor line is
select column_name
from all_tab_columns a
where table_name= 'EMP'
order by column_id; 

count3 number;
count4 number;
lines1 varchar2(3000) := '';  
lines2 varchar2(3000) := '';            
count1 number;
count2 number;
header1 varchar2(3000) := '';
header2 varchar2(3000) := '';
BEGIN
count2 := 0;
select count(1)
into count1
from all_tab_columns a
where table_name= 'EMP';
FOR I IN head LOOP
 count2 := count2+1;
 IF count2 != count1 THEN
 header1 := header1||'"'||i.column_name||'"'||',' ;
 ELSIF count1 = count2 THEN
 header1 := header1||'"'||i.column_name||'"' ;
 END IF;
END LOOP;
header2 := header1;

count4 := 0;
select count(1)
into count3
from all_tab_columns a
where table_name= 'EMP';
FOR I IN line LOOP
count4 := count4+1;
 IF count4 = 1 THEN
  lines1 := lines1||''''||'"'||''''||'||'||i.column_name ;
 ELSIF count4 != count3 THEN
  lines1 := lines1||'||'||''''||'"'||','||'"'||''''||'||'||i.column_name;
 ELSIF count3 = count4 THEN
  lines1 :=        lines1||'||'||''''||'"'||','||'"'||''''||'||'||i.column_name||'||'||''''||'"'||'''' ;
 END IF;
END LOOP;
 lines2 := lines1;

FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(fnd_file.output, header2);
EMAIL_TABLE2(lines2);
END;
```

/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMAIL_TABLE2(abc in varchar2) is
 xyz varchar2(1000);
 cursor lines is
 select abc a from EMP;  -- This is not working
BEGIN
  for i in lines loop
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(fnd_file.output,i.a);
  end loop;
END;
```

/

Above will be registered as a concurrent program, fnd_file.pu_line will be created in o||req_numebr||.out . I will be attaching this out file to email and mailing it.

Outfile should look something like this:

```
 "NAME","EMP_ID","DEPT","SAL"

 "JOHN","101","IT","10000"
 "ROB","102","SALES","8000"
```

the first line would be header from all_tab_columns, and lines are from the table which is passed as parameter.

plz let me know if the above works or else is their any way of doing it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is easier to remove the last comma rather than having to count the results first:

```
FOR I IN head LOOP
 header1 := header1||'"'||i.column_name||'"'||',';
END LOOP;

header1 := SUBSTR(header1, 1, LENGTH(header1)-1);
```

Next, your `EMAIL_TABLE2` procedure needs to use a ref cursor (`SYS_REFCURSOR`) if you want to build and use the column list dynamically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMAIL_TABLE2(abc in varchar2) is
 xyz varchar2(1000);
 lines SYS_REFCURSOR;
 l_query varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
  l_query := 'select '||abc||' a from EMP';  
  open lines for l_query;
  loop
      fetch lines INTO xyz;
      exit when lines%NOTFOUND;
      FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(fnd_file.output,xyz);
  end loop;
END;
```

More information on ref cursors here: http://www.orafaq.com/node/63

Comment: Thanks this was working good, but do u know how to email the out file as an attachment using UTL_SMTP or any other method.

Comment: There is a `UTL_MAIL` package that should do any email jobs you need, including attachments: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_mail.htm